# How to install / use / turn on SublimeLinter

Tags: sublimetext3

It’s taken me an hour and I’ve now installed SublimeLinter into SublimeText. But it doesn’t do anything.

Do I have to turn it on? I was expecting it to run while I'm coding? Update: it works automatically - you don't need to turn it on.

I’ve installed a CSS Linter plugin, but still doesn’t work (see http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/v3.10.10/installation.html)

It says something about “configure your PATH” so that SublimeLinter can find the Linter plugin. How do I do that?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". When asking, it's important to stick to the facts and avoid the fluff. "I can't believe how difficult this is." only sounds like whining. Where did you search and what steps did you try? You've only given us a high-level overview of the problem.

Comment: It's taken me a day but I've finally got SublimeLinter installed and working!

Comment: So, clearly and concisely explain the steps in an answer. SO will start a countdown and when it expires you'll be able to select the answer as the fix to the problem.

Comment: I don't have the faintest idea how i got it to work!